# PendingIntent.getBroadcast not working in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

my PendingIntent.getBroadcast is not working properly. I called pending intent in a different intent.But it is not working.

```
private static final int uniqueID = 12345;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //main = new MainActivity();
    final Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intent1);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    dbHandler = new DBHandler(this,null,null,1);


    //initialize alarm manager
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    //initialize timepicker
    timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    //initialize the text view
    //update_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.update_text);

    //create the instance of calender
    final Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();

    //create an intent
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReciever.class);

    //final TextView alarm_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarm_text);

    Button alarm_on= (Button)findViewById(R.id.alarm_on);

    alarm_on.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getHour());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getMinute());

                    int hour = timePicker.getHour();
                    int minute = timePicker.getMinute();

                    //convert into string
                    String hour_string= String.valueOf(hour);
                    String min_string = String.valueOf(minute);
                    if(hour>12){
                        time = hour_string+ ":"+min_string+ " PM";

                    }
                    else{
                        time = hour_string+":"+min_string+" AM";

                    }

                    //TextView update_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.update_text);
                    Toast.makeText(intent1.this, "alarm set to"+ time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //put in extra string into intent tells the clock that you pressed the alarm on
                    intent.putExtra("extra","alarm on");

                    //pending intent
                    pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(intent1.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    //set the alarm manager
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pending);

                    SQLiteDatabase db;
                    db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(DBHandler.COLUMN_TASK,time);
                    db.insertWithOnConflict(DBHandler.TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                    db.close();
                    startActivity(i);
                   // main.UpdateUI();

                }
            }
    );

    Button alarm_off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.alarm_off);

    alarm_off.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //TextView update_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarm_text);
                    update_text.setText("alarm off");
                    //cancel the pending intent
                    alarmManager.cancel(pending);
                    //put extra string into myintent
                    //tells the clock that you presses the off button
                    intent.putExtra("extra","alarm off");
                    //stop the ringtone
                    sendBroadcast(intent);



                }
            }
    );


}
```

Whenever the pending intent is called an error log is created so that is how I came to know that pending intent is not working
below is AlarmReciever.java which the pending Intent has to call.

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e( "we are in the reciever ","yay");

    //fetch extra string from intent
    String your_string = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
    Log.e("what is the key ",your_string );
    Intent service_intent = new Intent(context,RingtoneService.class);

    //pass the extra string to main activity thriugh this class
    service_intent.putExtra("extra",your_string);

    //start the ringtone service
    context.startService(service_intent);

}
```

}

Comment: `"But it is not working."` meaning what?

Comment: First, use a `WakefulBroadcatReceiver`, or my `WakefulIntentService`, with `_WAKEUP` alarms. Second, your alarm will be scheduled in the past if the `timePicker` has an hour and minute that is prior to the current time. Beyond that, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see if your alarm is actually being scheduled, and make sure that your `AlarmReceiver` is registered in the manifest.

Comment: you have a timepicker but do you change the time if so you need to listener to those changes apart from the comment already mentioned

Comment: I have used the same PendingIntent.getBroadcast in another app in which was an alarm.It was working perfectly in that app.In that app the alarm was in the main activity and it was calling other intents from the main activity.In my question above as you can see the pending intent is itself calling from an intent.I guess that is where the problem is??